# Method ignored when subclassing a type defined in a C module

Tags: python, subclassing, python-c-api, freecad

I am subclassing a type defined in a C module to alias some attributes and methods so that my script works in different contexts.

How is it that to get this to work, I have to tweak the dictionary of my class manually ? If I don't add a reference to `DistanceTo` in the dictionnary, I get `Point3d has no attribute named DistanceTo`.

```
class Point3d(App.Base.Vector):
      def __new__(cls, x, y, z):
          obj = super(Point3d, cls).__new__(cls)
          obj.x, obj.y, obj.z = x, y, z
          obj.__dict__.update({
               'X':property(lambda self: self.x),
               'Y':property(lambda self: self.y),
               'Z':property(lambda self: self.z),
               'DistanceTo':lambda self, p: self.distanceToPoint(p)})
          return obj
      def DistanceTo(self, p): return self.distanceToPoint(p)
```

I was thinking that once `__new__` had returned an instance I could still populate it with methods and attributes. Can anyone shed some light on this ?

EDIT : The module I import from is FreeCAD. The C base type is defined [there](https://github.com/FreeCAD/FreeCAD/blob/master/src/Base/PyObjectBase.cpp). Then Vector is derived form this definition [here](https://github.com/FreeCAD/FreeCAD/blob/master/src/Base/Vector3D.cpp)

EDIT2 : I also tried the following :

```
class Point3d(App.Base.Vector):
      def __new__(cls, x, y, z):
          obj = super(Point3d, cls).__new__(cls)
          obj.x, obj.y, obj.z = x, y, z
          obj.__dict__.update({
               'X': x, 'Y': y, 'Z': z,
               'DistanceTo':lambda self, p: self.distanceToPoint(p)})
           return obj
       def DistanceTo(self, p): return self.distanceToPoint(p)
```

and after creating a second point, both Point3d `p` returns the value of the last point for `p.X`, `p.Y` and `p.Z` no matter what `x,y,z` parameters were passed at the creation of the instance. `p.x, p.y, p.z` return the expected values. It seems to indicate that the dictionary is shared between instances.

EDIT 3 : Problem solved ! The Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE bit is set to zero to prevent subclassing as explained in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in  [`PyObjectBase.cpp`](https://github.com/FreeCAD/FreeCAD/blob/master/src/Base/PyObjectBase.cpp) :

```
/** \brief 
 * To prevent subclasses of PyTypeObject to be subclassed in Python we should remove 
 * the Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE flag. For example, the classes App::VectorPy  and App::MatrixPy
 * have removed this flag and its Python proxies App.Vector and App.Matrix cannot be subclassed.
 * In case we want to allow to derive from subclasses of PyTypeObject in Python
 * we must either reimplment tp_new, tp_dealloc, tp_getattr, tp_setattr, tp_repr or set them to
 * 0 and define tp_base as 0.
 */
```

This is due to the `App::VectorPy` class not being implemented to safely support subclassing and therefore the Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE bit is set to zero to prevent it from happening.

For information, it is a similar situation to the `bytes` built-in type that cannot be subclassed. See this [discussion](http://grokbase.com/t/python/python-3000/079g2br8a7/bytes-py-tpflags-basetype) to hear from Guido van Rossum why `bytes` is not subclassable.

Comment: I think this is a valid answer but I would recommend asking follow-up questions in a new question instead of in here.

Comment: Sorry I will open a new question after doing a bit of research.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you want to add the properties dynamically. Just use:

```
class Point3d(App.Base.Vector):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        super().__init__(x, y, z)  # or maybe  super().__init__([x, y, z])

    @property
    def X(self):
        return self[0]  # guessing that App.Base.Vector works like a list

    @property.setter
    def X(self, value):
        self[0] = value

    # Y and Z likewise.
```

Comment: Absolutely, that's what I tried first but I got a `Point3d has no attribute named 'X'`. I don't understand why I have to go under the hood to do this...

Comment: @JacquesGaudin: Check your indentation and try it again. You probably indented the properties wrong.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this. The indentation is correct, all spaces in my file but suffered during the copy-paste operation.